# How to find the appropriate isovalue with given probability to plot atomic orbitals

Tags: computational-chemistry, orbitals

As far as I know, a plot of orbitals is drawn by taking region with 90% probability for an electron to be found.

Meanwhile, the program which can plots orbitals, such as VMD, gets isovalue (`e/Å3`) to [find and draw the boundary surface of orbital](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/27292/what-is-an-orbital-boundary-surface).

I'm trying to write code which draws 2p orbital by taking region with given probability, so I need to calculate the isovalue from given probability.

However it is not easy... 2p orbital function looks like $P(r, \theta, \phi)$, so integrate it symbolically seems not to be able to find isovalue. Maybe I can perform binary search to find isovalue with numerical integration, but I think it's not so much effective. Are there other ways to solve this?

Comment: It may be better suited for mathematicians, unless anybody is aware of ready to use code.